# cross browser solution to specifying svg images using css

Tags: css

For flexibility I would like to specify images in css rather than inline.  For example, it allows me to switch images using :hover pseudo class.   However I am having a lot of difficulty finding a cross browser solution:  Below is some sample html which attempts to display an svg image via css using various methods.  For reference I also include img tag with image specified directly in tag.
For chrome only the image in content url appears to work.
For firefox and IE 11 only the image in background url appears to work
I am unable to find a method that works cross browser

```css
.test-content img {
  content: url("http://c.reapic1.com/camera.svg");
  width: 30px;
}

.test-after-content img:after {
  content: url("http://c.reapic1.com/camera.svg");
  width: 30px;
}

.test-before-content img:before {
  content: url("http://c.reapic1.com/camera.svg");
  width: 30px;
}

.test-background img {
  background: url("http://c.reapic1.com/camera.svg");
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image in src attribute</h1>
<img width="30" src="http://c.reapic1.com/camera.svg">
<h1>Image in content url</h1>
<div class="test-content">
  <img>
</div>
<h1>Image in before content url</h1>
<div class="test-before-content">
  <img>
</div>
<h1>Image in after content url</h1>
<div class="test-after-content">
  <img>
</div>
<h1>Image as background</h1>
<div class="test-background">
  <img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution for you. It looks like part of the issue is that you won't be able to use `<img>` I was able to use `<span>` as well as background to get it to work in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

[The code in plnkr](https://plnkr.co/vT40j2532D5D0puNSLg9?p=preview)

```css
.test-background span {
    background: url(https://material.io/tools/icons/static/icons/baseline-visibility-24px.svg) 100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
 }
.test-background span:hover {
   background: url("https://material.io/tools/icons/static/icons/baseline-visibility_off-24px.svg")  100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Image as background</h1>
  <div class="test-background">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```